# Jupiter's formation

Tags: planets, stellar-evolution, jupiter

Two days ago i went to a mathematics conference where there was a paper presented on Jupiter's formation via disk-instability model.

I know that there are two different theories for the formation of the planets.One of them is the **Core accretion** model and the other one is **disk-instability** model. I also tried to read this [paper on planetary formation](https://arxiv.org/ftp/astro-ph/papers/0703/0703237.pdf) in which they said 161 planets were put on to test.  90% followed Core accretion model and rest of them followed the later model. Did not say anything explicit about Jupiter.

Jupiter is too close to the Sun to follow the **Disk-Instability** model ( I am not sure completely ) .

Now i want to know which model Jupiter follows for its formation. And i do not want a Yes/No answer. I want the mathematical calculations too.

Comment: You can't say "I know" and then say "I am not sure" in the same sentence on the same point; that is dangerous for the dissemination of knowledge to the community.

Comment: Take a look at it https://www.space.com/18389-how-was-jupiter-formed.html